# Is the reason my database loses its selection over time a result of this URL with the autoReconnect property?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have some code that connects to a database using JDBC using a basic URL:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + getHostname() + ":" + getPort();
```

I am using the following arguments:

```
setProperty("connectTimeout", "2000");
setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
```

I don't include the database name, since it might not exist yet. I check whether one exist upon connection, and create it as needed. Then I select the database.

I use two queries:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS <name>
```

then

```
USE <name>
```

So the database is selected here upon connection.

The issue I'm having is that I saw an error in the log:

```
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

This doesn't make sense, because the database is *always* selected upon connection, otherwise an exception would have been thrown. However, this exception about a missing selection occurs hours later.

My guess is that, upon reconnecting, it uses the URL, which doesn't include the database name. So it reconnects, but now the database isn't selected.

Can someone confirm whether this is the cause of the behavior I am experiencing?

Comment: Why don't you create your database during connect with initSQL option?

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J explicitly says not to use statements like `USE <name>`, you should use `Connection.setCatalog(String)` for that. Exactly for reasons like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option `createDatabaseIfNotExist` exactly to do that.
Connector will then connect to server without database, create database is not existing and connect to that database.
database must then be explicitly set in connection string, like
"jdbc:mysql://myHost:3306/myDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"

The advantage is that if connection fails, autoreconnect will connect to the  database directly.

Answer (score 0):

`String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + getHostname() + ":" + getPort();`

You should include your database name. Your URL followed by a "/DBNAME".

`USE database` is for subsequent statements. The named database remains the default until the end of the session. Your session expires.

If you create the database on the fly, you can connect again using the complete URL with the database name at the end, not with `USE database`

Comment: I can't include the database name in the URL when it's not guaranteed to exist, otherwise the connection will fail with an exception: `com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Unknown database '<name>'`.

Comment: The USE statement tells MySQL to use the named database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements. The named database remains the default until the end of the session or another USE statement is issued.

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J documentation explicitly says not to use statements like `USE database`, instead `Connection.setCatalog(String)` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, hence, don't connect without a database name.

Try to connect with the name. In the catch block, check if this is the problem (SQLException has a `.getState()` method that returns a specific error code, check it against mysql's table, or just run the code passing a DB URL with a non-existent dbname and just print it out, now you know) - and if so, run a method that will create a new connection (without a dbname), creates the database, closes that connection, and returns. Then you retry *with* the database name. Remember, exceptions can be caught.